# How does Linux choose a IP address when a socket didn't specify the source IP address?

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming

As I said in the title,I want to know if a socket only specify the destination IP address,and don't specify the source IP address,how does the Linux kernel choose the source IP address?In random?

Answer (score 1):

It uses the routing table to determine the interface. See column "Iface" in `route` command output.